# How is Flux Architecture better than MVC

Tags: javascript, redux, ngrx

I try to understand what is the real problems flux architecture solve.

The first and main problem

- **Store** as a state management. Example from redux (flux architecture implementation) action -> store(reducer) -> view. This is an easy way to manage state.

But in a lot of blogs articles they talk about MVC / two way data binding.
I think it is wrong because I don't see how flux architecture cares about two way data binding. 
For example:

angularJs login Application:

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
  username<input ng-model="username">
  password<input ng-model="password">
  <button ng-click="submit()">Send</button>
</div>
```

script:

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('loginCtrl', function($scioe) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    globalStore.dispatch({
      action: 'LOGIN', 
      payload: {
        username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Sure I don't do this in real application but in this example I can use two way data binding and store. 
In this case [FLUX VS MVC](https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/flux-vs-mvc-design-patterns-57b28c0f71b7), the explanation is that one change can loop back and have cascading effects across the codebase (making things very complicated to debug and understand).

[FLUX VS MVC](http://voidcanvas.com/flux-vs-mvc/) in this case they say's flux is good implementation of flux

So I try to read about flux architecture on [flux official site](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html), they share a youtube video and explain MVC is get complex, and can infinte loop.

My questions:

1. What are the problems that flux architecture solves?
2. What are real examples for MVC or/and two way binding problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to think more in terms of MVC vs CBA(component based architecture) rather than Redux vs MVC.

Redux helps you synchronize state between your components and really shines when you got complex component trees that share state.

I would like to point you to this excellent presentation that may help you understand the benefits of using Redux in a component based architecture.

Managing State in Angular 2 - St Louis Angular Lunch - Kyle Cordes
https://youtu.be/eBLTz8QRg4Q

Comment: thank you so much, i fill that angular 2 get only one benefits from redux(flux architecture)... the state in one place. i fillredux is not vs mvc, it's mvc with one model(state),and for angular 2 component is controller + view

Answer (score 1):

Facebook created the Flux pattern to solidify state management between a lot of React components.  With React, every component is capable of maintaining it's own state.   Because of this, we need to be careful how we lay out our architecture for our components.  Typically speaking we try to look at development as one large component with many smaller components sitting inside of it... with much of the state management maintained by the outermost component.   This works well for a lot of things but not everything.

So Flux was invented to compliment React's unidirectional data flow to assist in creating a easier to reason about state system between React components.   Redux is a similar implementation of Flux but instead makes it much easier to reason about, as Redux only has one state store shared by all components.

To sum up the entire problem Flux and Redux tries to solve we have to consider the alternatives for one isolated component to be able to communicate effectively with another.   React has a unidirectional flow of parent child components but what happens when we have to communicate outside of that?   That is where having a state store outside of the component makes a lot of sense.  The contrary would be to setup manual events and event listeners between components which gets messy very fast.

Comment: thank you for answer!, i understand the facebook problem to understand flux, but i do not found problem with mvc they just use single model(store) with all data and all component subscribe for the single model(store). where the problem with two way data binding or with mvc? over the web all say's in mvc if your app growth is start to be infinite loop, i cant find example for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook [explains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYkdrAPrdcw) that MVC quickly became complex**, and it was difficult to onboard new developers.

> *"The biggest difference between Flux and MVC is that you avoid cascading updates"* - [video source at relevant time](https://youtu.be/nYkdrAPrdcw?t=1080)

So they switched to Flux, which is more FP than OOP in style.

But Flux is really just MVC properly implemented on client-side (taking into account that user actions also has to go through the Controller, not merely server interactions).

[See the diagram here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYkdrAPrdcw&t=736s).

> Store = Model
>
> Dispatcher = Controller
>
> View = View

Where the View only gets to talk to the Dispatcher/Controller, instead of talking directly to the Store/Model (as opposed to what they had in their buggy MVC implementation; which was based on observables, [as heard here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYkdrAPrdcw&t=2233s)).

The main difference from vanilla MVC being that the Dispatcher ensures that:

> *"Until your Store layer is completely done, the views or anything else can't put an action through the system."* - [video source at
> relevant time](https://youtu.be/nYkdrAPrdcw?t=1182).

** - I can only guess it was because of "God objects", or "Fat models", and increasing coupling, due to (poor) OOP.